# ctypes.cdll load library from memory rather than file

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I keep small programs with same interface(.so files) in database and have wrapper that uses them by loading with ctypes.cdll.

Is there a way to load them from memory? Currently I create temporary file for this and then pass filename to ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(), but feel this not to be the best solution.

Comment: Generally no because `CDLL` calls POSIX `dlopen` or Windows `LoadLibrary` to load a shared library properly, i.e. memory-map the library and its dependent libraries, do runtime linking to resolve symbols, and call the module constructors / entry point. Doing all of that manually would require you to build your own loader for each platform.

Comment: @eryksun thanks. I felt that it was made that way purposely. I'll keep question open in case someone made workaround I can use

Comment: py2exe has a [memory loader](http://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/py2exe-3/source/MemoryModule.c) for Windows PE DLLs. It would be a major undertaking, but this could be extended to support Linux ELF and OS X Mach-O libraries.